# How to set request priority using retrofit2 in android?

Tags: android, request, retrofit2

As per link [Retrofit Vs Volley](http://vickychijwani.me/retrofit-vs-volley/),  Retrofit does not support setting request priority. But i want to set priorities of request.

Is there any way to do this task? Thank you for help !

Comment: Then why not use the library that supports it?  Or as Retrofit is open source you could alter the code of the library, but its going to be a fair amount of work.

Comment: @GabeSechan Actually i am android beginner. Performance of retrofit is better than other libraries that's why i am using it.

Comment: You're worried about the performance of a networking library?  I assure you the time spent waiting for data will dwarf the time spent requesting it.  Not to mention that isn't really true, benchmarks are mixed and all depends on how you set it up.  If you need a feature a library doesn't support, be prepared to spend programmer time to add the feature, or use a library that does.